# How to call controller method from the app.js in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I want to call the controller method [getFacility()] from the app.js file. 
but when I used the below code segment I got the error like

> `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:`

here my controller files and service files

app.js

```
...
...     
.state('facilityHome.editFacility', 
{
   url: '/editFacility/:facilityId',
   templateUrl: '/views/facility/newFacility.html',
   controller: 
        function($scope, $stateParams, facilityController) {
                facilityController.getFacility($stateParams.facilityId);
         }
}

....
...
```

facilityControlelr.js

```
app.controller('facilityController',
['$scope', '$rootScope','$location','$filter', 'facilityService',
    function ($scope, $rootScope,$location,$filter, facilityService){

        /* Assign Object */
        var facilityScope = this;

        /* Initialize DTO Object */
        facilityScope.facilityDTO={
            id:null,
            version:null,
            facilityName:"",
            description:""
        };


        /* Initialize Object Array */
        facilityScope.facilityList = [];


        facilityScope.getFacility=function(id){
            facilityService.fetchFacility(id)
                .then(
                function(successRespond) {
                    $scope.facilityDTO = successRespond;
                },
                function(errResponse){
                    console.error('Error while fetching');
                    console.error(errResponse);
                }
            );

        };

    }
]);
```

Here What I got in my console.

> "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: facilityControllerProvider
>   <- facilityController
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=facilityControllerProvider%20%3C-NaNacilityController
>   minErr/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:68:12
>   createInjector/providerCache.$injector<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:4397:19
>   getService@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:4550:39
>   createInjector/protoInstanceInjector<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:4402:28
>   getService@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:4550:39
>   injectionArgs@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:4574:58
>   instantiate@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:4616:18
>   $ControllerProvider/this.$gethttps://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:9870:18
>   z/<.compile/<@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:23873
>   invokeLinkFn@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:9492:9
>   nodeLinkFn@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:8978:11
>   compositeLinkFn@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:8226:13
>   publicLinkFn@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:8106:30
>   compilationGenerator/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:8447:20
>   l@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:23072
>   y/l.compile/https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:23492
>   $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttps://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:17143:15
>   v/y.transitionTo/y.transition<@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:18793
>   processQueue@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:15552:28
>   scheduleProcessQueue/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:15568:27
>   $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttps://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:16820:16
>   $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttps://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:16636:15
>   $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttps://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:16928:13
>   done@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:11266:36
>   completeRequest@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:11464:7
>   requestLoaded@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:11405:9

Comment: Why not inject the state in the controller instead?

Comment: Could you create plnkr?

Comment: Could you please explain, what are you trying to achieve by this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To inject a controller into another controller, use the `$controller` service.

```
.state('facilityHome.editFacility', 
{
   url: '/editFacility/:facilityId',
   templateUrl: '/views/facility/newFacility.html',
   controller: 
       function($scope, $stateParams, $controller) {
           var facCtrl = $controller("facilityController", {'$scope': $scope});
           facCtrl.getFacility($stateParams.facilityId);
       }
}
```

Because the `facilityController` manipuates `$scope`, `$scope` needs to be injected as a **local**.

For more information,see [AngularJS $controller Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller).

Answer (score -1):

You can't inject a Controller in another Controller. You need a Factory/Service.

See some documentation : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Comment: If so how I can call the controller method from the inside the `$stateProvider.state` ?

Comment: You can't. You need a service, to share data/logic between controllers.

Comment: can't is not right.. though its not recommended. A controller can be injected to another.